# can I use EJS with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ejs

Hi I am new to AngularJS. I have great web app already running with JQuery and jQuery UI.

Now I want to completely get rid of JQuery and am going to migrate to Angularjs because of its MVC (MVW) pattern.

So my jQuery application is running with EJS for templates and entirely DOM manipulation. But when I think about Angular js, I have doubts. Can I still use EJS or not?

So please guide me whether I can use or not.

Another doubt is, let's assume I have list page. It is updated dynamically, and it will display 10 records first then based on user scroll, the next 10 records will be appended in the DOM after AJAX. Can we append to the DOM dynamically using Angular?

How do I achieve these kind of things in Angular?

Answer (score 18):

You can use EJS (server or client side) in combination with Angular but there's no need and you'll probably overcomplicate things. AngularJS is very capable for manipulating the DOM by itself in a very *separation of concerns* kind of way. The most elegant way to work with Angular is to have a *RESTful* backend and just serve some static html/js files from a webserver.

As for endless scrolling, there are [tons of ready to use plugins (modules)](https://www.google.nl/search?q=endless+scrolling+angularjs&oq=endless+scrolling+angularjs) to choose from or you can write your own. Basically this will need a view with a [ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to display the currently loaded items and a directive that will notify a [controller/scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) to load more items when the user is scrolling down.
A nice simple article can be found [here](https://coderwall.com/p/cl7zyg).

Similar questions:

- [Mixing angular and asp.net mvc webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097592/mixing-angular-and-asp-net-mvc-web-api/21098239#21098239)
- [Actual use of jade template and angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989024/actual-use-of-jade-template-and-angularjs/20990498#20990498)

Comment: But you may need to use it with EJS sometimes. For example, you're using expressjs who need a html template.

Comment: I would not say there is *no need*.  If you want data to be available *as soon as the page loads*, you'll need to use a templating engine.  If you're ok with load times, no matter how small, then you can get away with only using Angular.

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course you can use `EJS` with `Angular JS`. You might want to have a look at this;

https://gist.github.com/jrmoran/4277025

And about your DOM manipulation question. Yes you can append DOM dynamically using Angular JS. Angular JS have a strong feature of `two way data binding` which dynamically updates its DOM content when a model variable changes.

Have a look at this:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding