# .ejs when compared to .html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have a `Node Js` project where I have all front end files in `.ejs` which calls the `server.js` which is doing back end work.

1)Does `ejs` provide more functionality when compared to `html` ?

2)Is this the node expressJs functionality ?

3)Can I do angularJs keeping extension as `.ejs`? eg:`ng-controller`  Confused;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*1) Does ejs provide more functionality when compared to html ?*

Yes, [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) and [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) are template engine for node.js and express. With they it's possible to do conditions and access variables returns from the server. Doen't is necessary to send HTML code to the response. They mix all functionality HTML (js, jquery, bootstrap, etc) plus template engine advantages.

*2) Is this the node expressJs functionality ?*

Is this node.js functionality.

*3) Can I do angularJs keeping extension as .ejs? eg:ng-controller*

Similar questions:

- [can i use EJS with Angular js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342408/can-i-use-ejs-with-angular-js)
- [Actual use of Jade template and angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989024/actual-use-of-jade-template-and-angularjs/20990498#20990498)

Answer (score 4):

`ejs` is just a template engine.

It makes possible for you to load data from your application in the view.

For instance, in your code `<title><%= title %></title>`, `title` is a variable from your application, and what is gonna show on the screen is the variable's value.

After the template is rendered, it generates a `.html` file for the browser.

You can still use `Angular` normally.

Comment: But it works with .html as well right ?

Comment: Yes, you can add your Angular directives in both `.html` and `.ejs` files.