# Express routing to html with json data

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, express, routes

following problem: 
I am running an Nodejs server together with a mongoDB. By now I have always sent the results of my queries as json-data to the browser.

```
    app.get('/gesamtergebnis', function(req,res){

    User.aggregate([{$group: { 
            _id: "$Art",
            Anzahl: {$sum: "$Anzahl"}
        }

        }], function(err,docs){

        if(err){console.log(err);}
        else {res.json(docs);}  

    });

});
```

My results are - what is the nature of those json responses - poorly formatted. So I have set up an html-file with a table ect. and a little ng-controller to get the data in the table with ng-repeat - no problem
so far.

```
function AppCtrl($scope, $http) {
console.log("Hello from AppCtrl")

var showTotal = function(){

    $http.get('./gesamtergebnis').success(function(response){

            console.log("I got the data I requested!");
        $scope.gesamtergebnis = response;

    });
}
```

}

My routing is:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")); In the public folder is my index.html
```

My problem is: The index.html does not receive any server response;

I need to

- route a request to a certain html (res.sendfile does not helpt as I cannot add json data to the response) and
- send the json data from the mongodb request within the same route command

Is there no way to redirect the server response to a certain html (also other htmls then index) endpoint with data?

What is the best way to solve this? Get the routing done on the client side with Angular? How can I do this easily?

Any help would be great!

Hucho

Comment: is this for you to debug the responses or do you want your api to display json on html by design?

Answer (score 0):

First, Express is a framework and provide the template structure, so it's good to put the files of frontend in the folder *views*, not in static. Static is more used for import libs, js, css...
Second, for comunicate server side with frontend in node, it's recomended to use some engine, like [ejs](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) or [jade](http://jade-lang.com/); angular can be used with these too, somethink this:

- [can i use EJS with Angular js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342408/can-i-use-ejs-with-angular-js)
- [Actual use of Jade template and angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989024/actual-use-of-jade-template-and-angularjs)

Now, how to use and send json data to view, or view to server, search for similar question and consult the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your advice...I will go throug the links provided!